# Jquery image stack animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have no skill with javascript or jquery. So i have tried to figure this out as best i can.

Im using jQuery 1.9.1 at the moment.

What im trying to do, is unpack or unstack a pile of images when the top image is clicked on (it must of course repack when it is clicked on again)...

The images are positioned just like in the image, using css :nth-child()...

Here is my attempt at the jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var $profile = $('.profile');
        $profile.click(function(){

            $(this).toggleClass("active");
            $(".thumb").children().eq(1).animate({left:'150px'});
            $(".thumb").children().eq(2).animate({left:'150px'});
            $(".thumb").children().eq(3).animate({left:'150px'});
            $(".thumb").children().eq(4).animate({left:'150px'});
            $(".thumb").children().eq(5).animate({left:'150px'});
            $(".thumb").children().eq(6).animate({left:'150px'});
            $(".thumb").children().eq(7).animate({left:'150px'});
            $(".thumb").children().eq(8).animate({left:'150px'});
            $(this).siblings(".user-info").toggleClass("active");       

        });
    });
```

I Have tried for three days now to pretty much learn jquery to achieve this task, if anyone could help me id greatly appreciate it!!

[Here is what it looks like](http://rowanpereira.com/test/test/)

[Here is an image to better illustrate](http://rowanpereira.com/test/test/img.jpg)

Comment: Could you add a piece of your html code please.

Comment: If the animation is the same on all elements you can simply use: `$(".thumb").children().animate();`. If it differs, try to query only once and re-use the result as a variable like this: `var e = $(".thumb").children(); e.eq(0).animate(); […]`.

Comment: What you mean is that you have a set of images on the top of one another, and you want them to get put in line horizontally or vertically when the first one is clicked, right ?

Comment: If you're using CSS3 selector, why no position images using CSS and add a CSS3 transition? When top image clicked you would just add a class to the images container like "unstacked" and images will unstack based on CSS-defined positions.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can achieve this:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://rowanpereira.com/test/test/img/person1/1.jpg" alt="" class="stacked" />
    <img src="http://rowanpereira.com/test/test/img/person1/1.jpg" alt="" class="stacked" />
    <img src="http://rowanpereira.com/test/test/img/person1/1.jpg" alt="" class="stacked" />
    <img src="http://rowanpereira.com/test/test/img/person1/1.jpg" alt="" class="stacked" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    overflow: scroll-x;
}

img 
{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}
.stacked
{
    position: absolute;
}

.unstacked
{
    display: inline;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $("img").hover(function () {
        $("img").animate().toggleClass("stacked", "unstacked");
    });
});
```

Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/TdNz4/

This is just an example, of course you'll need to adapt it to fit your design.